Screen turns black after 2 minutes of inactivity
Fresh Debian install with XFCE and then installed i3wm which I mainly use (selecting it during login).
I've tried several approaches, such as xset s off -dpms, xset 1200 1200 1200 and other use of xset. I've added the following configuration to ~/.config/i3/config:
exec --no-startup-id xset s off -dpms

Creating a /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-serverflags.conf with
Section "ServerFlags"
    Option "StandbyTime" "20"
    Option "SuspendTime" "25"
    Option "OffTime" "30"
EndSection

is also ineffective (X11 restarted after this config).
Lastly, I've try using caffeine which again is ineffective.
Ideally, my goal is to prevent screen to turn black when watching fullscreen video. Could anyone explain to me what I'm missing ? Why are those configuration not taken into account ?

Culprit was xfce-power-manager, as I installed XFCE and i3. Adding exec --no-startup-id killall xfce4-power-manager to my config fixes the issue, but other conflict may exist
